# how to remove specific elements but not the text inside it using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

This is my Input xml

```
<para>
<a><b>this is a text</b></a>
</para>
```

this is my expected output

```
<para>
this is a text
</para>
```

how can i delete all the "a" tags and the "b" tags only and the text will not be affected using xslt thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="//para">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

(or to avoid white space from other child elements:

```
<xsl:template match="//para">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="./*/*/text()"></xsl:value-of>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: NB: Martin's answer's also good - we've approached in different ways.  His code goes through all elements, and if it sees `a` or `b` just removes them, keeping any content.  My approach finds the `para` element, then pulls the inner text (value) from it without pulling back any of the markup.

Comment: after the transformation there are alot of huge spaces how can i get rid with that??

Comment: Good point; this pulls back text (including white space) from all elements under para; Martin's solution's better there; or you could do a combination (amended above).

Answer (score 1):

Start with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then add

```
<xsl:template match="a | b">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

to handle your elements.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solve..

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//*/text()">
  <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)">
    <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat(normalize-space(.), '&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]" />
```