# How to remove xml tags only using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

```
<document>
    <body>
        <p>
            <pPr>
                <autoSpaceDE/>
                <autoSpaceDN/>
                <adjustRightInd/>
                <spacing/>
                <rPr>
                    <rFonts/>
                    <b/>
                    <bCs/>
                    <lang/>
                </rPr>
            </pPr>
            <r>
                <rPr>
                    <rFonts/>
                    <b/>
                    <bCs/>
                    <lang/>
                </rPr>
                <t>Title</t>
            </r>
        </p>
    </body>
</document>
```

How can i remove some tags without affecting or deleting the text inside
this is my expected output after xslt

```
<document><body><p>Title</p></body></document>
```

Comment: Can you please post your try.

Comment: **Please don't ask the same question twice!!** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362715/how-to-remove-specific-elements-but-not-the-text-inside-it-using-xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can follow one of two strategies:

1. Start with the *identity transform* template that copies everything as the default; then add templates to match any nodes you want to modify as the exception; This is what you started to do - now you only need to add empty template/s to remove the nodes you don't want.
2. Pick only the nodes you want; since there is only one, this would be by far the preferred strategy in this case:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="document/body/p/r/t" />
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

returning the **result** of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>Title</p>
```

---

The above is assuming you actually want the specific value of the `<t>` element - not just *any* text node/s that happen to be descendant/s of the `<p>` element of your input. If this assumption is incorrect, do this instead:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="document/body/p" />
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer and is good for me

```
<xsl:template match="//*/text()">
  <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)">
    <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat(normalize-space(.), '&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

I used this one  and now my problem is how can i remove the tags that has an empty value

```
<p/>
```

How can i eliminate that tag after transformation? Thank you